# Core bluetooth create CBUUID with data

Tags: swift, uuid, core-bluetooth

So I'm pretty new at the whole bluetooth stuff and I've been making a project and everything worked out fine so far, but when I got the UUIDS that we are supposed to use I got something like this:

```
0xD7, 0x36, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x6E, 0x12, 0x26, 0x80, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xE4, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x67
```

when I've been using strings so far, I assume that it should be done with the data constructor for CBUUID but no idea how to actually do it, anyone knows a way to either convert those values to a string uuid or just use them as is to create a CBUUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize a new Data object with your bytes and pass the data object to the `CBUUID` data [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid/1518799-init):

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0xD7, 0x36, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x6E, 0x12, 0x26, 0x80, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xE4, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x67]
let data = Data(bytes)
let cbuuid = CBUUID(data: data)
```

or simply:

```
let cbuuid = CBUUID(data: Data([0xD7, 0x36, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x6E, 0x12, 0x26, 0x80, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xE4, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x67]))
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work, will try again when I have the device to check, maybe I made a mistake somewhere, Thanks.